# The set of all $x$ satisfying, $\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{7-x} = 6 $, consists of:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radical-equations

> The set of all $x$ satisfying, $\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{7-x} = 6 $, consists of:

> $A)$ Two rational numbers. $B)$ An irrational number. $C)$ Complex number. $D)$ None.

How to solve the above question using proper method?

I got the values by substitution. I just considered the values after evaluation of the radical to be $(5,1)$ ,$(3,3)$ and $(4,2)$.

This leads me to nice and whole values of $x = 6$. I can't find any other solutions.

I tried squaring, but the solution is getting really nasty at a point. I wonder if there could be any more methods to solve this problem. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean, $\sqrt{4x+1}$ instead of $\sqrt{4x-1}$?

Comment: @Destiny If you know trigonometry then there is a nice method to solve such equations

Comment: It has two rational roots over $[-\frac 14,7]\\$   https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lxb2nau18g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{7-x}=6&\implies4x+1+7-x+2\sqrt{4x+1}\sqrt{7-x}=36\\&\iff2\sqrt{4x+1}\sqrt{7-x}=28-3x\\&\implies4(4x+1)(7-x)=(28-3x)^2\\&\iff25 x^2-276 x+756=0\\&\iff x=6\text{ or }x=\frac{126}{25}.\end{align}And you can easily check that $6$ and $\frac{126}{25}$ are actually roots of the original equation.

Comment: +1 Very nice distinctions drawn between $\implies$ and $\iff$.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG $\sqrt{4x+1}=6\cos^2t$  and $\sqrt{7-x}=6\sin^2t$

$\implies4x+1=36\cos^4t,7-x=36\sin^4t$

$\implies36\cos^4t+144\sin^4t=\cdots=29$

$\implies36\cos^4t+144(1-\cos^2t)^2=\cdots=29$

$\iff180\cos^4t-288\cos^2t+115=0$

$\implies\cos^2t=\dfrac56,\dfrac{23}{30}$

$\implies x=\dfrac{36(\cos^2t)^2-1}4=?$

Answer (score 1):

Here's is a variation of Jose's answer, which appeared as I was typing this up:

$$\sqrt{4x+1} + \sqrt{7-x} = 6 \\
\iff \sqrt{4x+1} = 6 - \sqrt{7-x} $$
$$\implies 4x+1 = 36+(7-x) - 12\sqrt{7-x}\tag{1} \\
\iff 5x-42=12\sqrt{7-x} $$
$$\implies 25x^2+1764-420x=144(7-x) \tag{2}\\
\iff 25x^2-276x+756=0 \\
\iff x=6\text{ or }\frac{126}{25}$$

The steps labelled (1) & (2) aren't invertible and [might have created extraneous solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3927547/21813); a quick check verifies that both $6$ and $\frac{126}{25}$ indeed satisfy the original equation.

Comment: It is better to write $126/25$ to emphasize that it is a rational number, and not merely some real number rounded to two decimals $5.04$.