# $( 1 - \sin x ) ( 1 + \csc x ) = \cos x \; , \; 0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi$

Tags: trigonometry

I found some solutions to this problem however I appear to be missing some solutions. Could anyone help me find the whole solution set?
$$( 1 - \sin x ) ( 1 + \csc x ) = \cos x \; , \; 0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi$$
$$1 + \csc x - \sin x - \sin x \csc x = \cos x $$
$$ 1 + \frac {1}{\sin x} - \sin x - 1 = \cos x $$
$$ \frac {1}{\sin x} - \sin x = \cos x $$
$$ \frac {1}{\sin x} = \cos x + \sin x $$
$$ 1 = \sin x (\cos x + \sin x) $$
$$ \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = \sin x \cos x + \sin^2 x $$
$$ \cos^2 x = \sin x \cos x $$
$$ \cos x = \sin x $$
$$ \frac {\sin x}{\cos x} = 1 $$
$$\tan x = 1$$
$$ x = \frac \pi 4, \, \frac {5 \pi}{4}$$

Comment: The step of dividing by $\cos x$ may have eliminated solutions, I would recommend revisiting the line prior to that step.

Comment: @abiessu Thank you for your advice. I can't seem to figure out what to do instead. Can you provide another hint?

Comment: I'm not certain of the results yet, but the double-angle formulas for $\sin,\cos$ seem to be relevant in that case.

Comment: Instead of dividing by $\cos x$, subtract $\sin x \cos x$ from both sides and then factor to get $\cos x(\cos x-\sin x)=0$. Then either $\cos x=0$ or $\cos x=\sin x$. In similar situations, rather than divide by a common factor on each side of the equation, instead, subtract, then divide by the common factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > $$( 1 - \sin x ) ( 1 + \csc x ) = \cos x \; , \; 0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi\tag{*}\\\ldots$$
   > $$ \cos^2 x = \sin x \cos x \tag A$$
   > $$ \cos x = \sin x $$
   > $$ \frac {\sin x}{\cos x} = 1 \tag B$$
   > $$\tan x = 1$$
   > $$ x = \frac \pi 4, \, \frac {5 \pi}{4}$$

   You divided equation $(A)$ by $\cos^2x$ to obtain equation $(B).$ Notice that this move implicitly assumes that the former has no solution satisfying $\cos^2x=0.$ But this assumption is unjustifiable.

   You ought to have factorised it out instead:
   $$ \cos^2 x = \sin x \cos x \tag A$$
   $$ \cos^2 x \big(\ 1-\tan x \big)=0\\
      \cos x=0 \;\text{or}\;\tan x =1$$
   $$x=\frac \pi 4\:\text{or}\:\frac \pi 2\:\text{or}\:\frac {5 \pi}4\:\text{or}\:\frac {3 \pi}2\tag#$$
2. But we are not quite done. Notice that our work so far has the following structure
      if Line $1$ is true, then so is Line $2$
      if Line $2$ is true, then so is Line $3$
      ...
      if Line $n{-}1$ is true, then so is Line $n$
   but nothing indicates that Line $n$ (the solution statement) actually implies Line $1$ (the given equation)?

   This means that we have potentially introduced [extraneous solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3927547/21813). Thus, to finish our work, we must check each solution in $(\#)$ to see whether it *actually* satisfies the given equation $(*).$ In this example, all the four solutions happen to be genuine.

Answer (score 1):

Using your equation $$\sin x(\sin x + \cos x) = 1$$ the additional solutions you missed were $$\sin x = 1 \rightarrow x = \dfrac {\pi}{2}, \dfrac {3 \pi}{2}$$  The other solutions are correct.