# How to prove $x + 3 = (x + 1)^2 \Leftarrow x=-2\;\text{or}\;1 \,? \quad \sqrt{x+3}=x+1 \Leftarrow x=1 \, ? \quad x^2 = x \Leftarrow x=0 \; $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't deduce the $\color{blue}\impliedby$ of [the 3 blue biconditionals below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3927547). How do I explicitly wrest or wring out the red functions in terms of *x*, from the 1 or 2 integers on the RHS?

Doubtless, I know that the RHS's  roots satisfy the LHS!  For example, for the first equation, I know $-2 + 3 \equiv  \color{red}{(-2 + 1)^2}, 1 + 3 \equiv  \color{red}{(3 + 1)^2}$. But it doesn't suffice to evaluate functions with 1 or 2 integers, because this
merely verifies the $\color{blue}\impliedby$ for merely 2 integers of $x$! We need to prove the $\color{blue}\impliedby \forall \, x$. Hence our conclusion must express the red functions in terms of $x$!

1. > $x+3=\color{red}{(x+1)^2} \color{blue}{\iff} x=-2\;\text{or}\;1\;$

   $x = -2 \iff x \color{limegreen}{+3} = -2 \color{limegreen}{+3} \iff x + 3 = 1.$

   OR $\quad x = 1 \iff x \color{limegreen}{+3} = 1 \color{limegreen}{+3} \iff x + 3 = 4.$ Then how to deduce $\color{red}{(x+1)^2}$?
2. > $\color{red}{\sqrt{x+3}}=x+1 \color{blue}{\iff} x=1 $

   $x = 1 \iff x \color{limegreen}{+1} =  1 \color{limegreen}{+1} \iff x + 1 = 2.$ Then how to deduce $\color{red}{\sqrt{x+3}}$?
3. > $\color{red}{x^2 = x} \color{blue}{\iff} x=0\;\text{or}\;1$

   $x = 1 \iff x \color{limegreen}{\cdot x} = 1 \color{limegreen}{\cdot x} \iff x^2 = x.$ I have no question on this case, which works!

   But
   $x = 0 \iff x \color{limegreen}{\cdot x} = 0 \color{limegreen}{\cdot x} \iff x^2 = 0.$ Then how to deduce $\color{red}{x^2 = x}$?

Comment: I answered to your explicit question, e.g. How to deduce $\sqrt {x+3}$ ? If my interpretation of your question is correct.

Comment: I fail to understand what is confusing you. Simply substitute $-2$ and $1$ instead of $x$ and see that the equation $x+3=(x+1)^2$ becomes true. I feel that you think this is not good enough, but _why do you think so_? Yes, it is _that_ simple. Of course, for the implication $\implies$ you need some tools, e.g. quadratic equation. The reason nobody mentions much the converse implication $\impliedby$ is precisely because it is completely trivial.

Comment: @lonestudent Thank you. You answered my question 2. Can you answer my questions 1 and 3 too please?

Comment: @user1176240 Sure . I will expand my answer . Likewise, I will answer your other $3$ questions.  I left it at $2$.  Because I wasn't sure if I understood your question correctly .

Comment: @user1176240  Please, tell me : Does my answer really answer your 2nd question?  Does it really explain at least a little bit what you want to ask?

Comment: Ah, I see. To prove the converse implication $\impliedby$ you only care to prove the LHS is true _when the RHS is true_. That is why you need to test only two values of $x$. It is irrelevant whether the LHS is true when the RHS is false. Recall the truth table for implication: $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}p&q&p\implies q\\\hline\bot&\bot&\top\\\bot&\top&\top\\\top&\bot&\bot\\\top&\top&\top\end{array}$$

Comment: This closely matches natural logic. If you want to check if the sentence "All fish live in the water" is true, you _only need to check the fish_. (And, if you find one that does not live in the water, then it is false; otherwise it is true.) You don't need to check any other non-fish animals, say mammals. (Whether _they_ live in the water is irrelevant, and as a matter of fact some do, and some don't). The same as it is irrelevant, in your case, whether the LHS is true for the $x$ that is neither $1$ or $-2$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you. Your comments answer my question. Why did you comment, rather than writing an answer though?

Comment: It is because I was not sure I'd fully understood your concerns. Now that it seems I _had_, I may turn those comments into an answer. Quite a lot of people on this site jump into answering before fully grasping what exactly is bothering the asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *explicit* answer is to your questions :

The algebraic steps you used to construct the *original* equations are correct, however these algebraic steps do *not* allow us to derive the original equations .

---

For instance :

$$\begin{align}\color{red}{\sqrt{x+3}}&=x+1 \color{blue}{\iff} x=1 \end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}x = 1 &\iff x \color{limegreen}{+1} =  1 \color{limegreen}{+1} \\
&\iff x + 1 = 2.\end{align}$$

Then how to deduce $\color{red}{\sqrt{x+3}} \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace ?$

---

Recall that, you have :

$$
\begin{align}&\sqrt {x+3}=x+1\\\\
\iff &\begin{cases}x+3=(x+1)^2\\ x+1≥0\end{cases}\\\\
\iff &\begin{cases}x^2+x-2=0\\
x+1≥0\end{cases}\\\\
\iff &\begin{cases} x\in\{-2,1\}\\
 x≥-1\end{cases}\\\\
\iff &x=1 \quad\tiny{\blacksquare}\end{align}
$$

You can now *reverse* the steps :

$$
\begin{align}x=1&\iff\begin{cases} x\in\{-2,1\}\\
x≥-1\end{cases}\\\\
&\iff \begin{cases}x^2+x-2=0\\
x+1≥0\end{cases}\\\\
&\iff \begin{cases}x+3=(x+1)^2\\ x+1≥0\end{cases}\\\\
&\iff \sqrt {x+3}=x+1 \\\\
&\iff x+1=\sqrt {x+3} \quad\tiny{\blacksquare}\end{align}
$$

Note that the following equivalence relations are *also* valid :

$$
\begin{align}x=1&\iff x+1=1+1\\
&\iff x+1=2\end{align}
$$

As you can see, the algebraic steps are all *consistent* and there is *no* contradiction between them .  However, depending on the result you want to achieve, i.e. for our purposes, it is important what algebraic steps you will take .

Comment: Many thanks! $\color{red}{1.}$ How does $\begin{cases}x+3=(x+1)^2\\ x+1≥0\end{cases} \iff \sqrt{x + 3} = x + 1$ ? Kindly show more steps? $\color{red}{2.}$ Shall you list out  the steps for equations 1 and 3 please? Or are you doing so for merely equation 2? Is this your final answer?

Comment: @user1176240 I will expand my answer as soon as possible . I will cover all your concerns .

Comment: Many thanks!!! No rush. Take your time.

Comment: @user1176240 Thank you. I will comment you, after expanding .

Answer (score 5):

1. $$x=p \:\:\text{or}\:\:q$$ is abbreviation for $$x=p \quad\text{or}\quad x=q.$$
2. The statement $$P(x)\impliedby \big(R(x)\quad\text{or}\quad S(x)\big)$$ implicitly means that whenever either $R(x)$ or $S(x)$ **is true** for some value of $x,$ $P(x)$ **is also true** for the same value. Logically, this means $$\text{for each }x,\big(R(x){\implies} P(x)\big)\quad\textbf{and}\quad\text{for each }x,\big(S(x){\implies} P(x)\big).$$

So, to prove $$\color{red}{x+3}=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}\impliedby x=-2\:\:\text{or}\:\:1\tag1$$ just means to argue this:

- for $x=-2,$ $$\color{red}{x+3}=1=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2};$$
- while for $x=1,$ $$\color{red}{x+3}=4=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}.\tag2$$

> > $x+3=\color{red}{(x+1)^2} \color{blue}{\iff} x=-2\;\text{or}\;1\;$
>
> $x = -2 \iff x \color{limegreen}{+3} = -2 \color{limegreen}{+3} \iff x + 3 = 1.$
>
> OR $\quad x = 1 \iff x \color{limegreen}{+3} = 1 \color{limegreen}{+3} \iff x + 3 = 4.$ Then how to deduce $\color{red}{(x+1)^2}$?

1. Replace the logically incorrect `or` with `and` or `but` or `while` or somesuch.
2. Are you just working in the reverse direction? Then display `⟸` instead of `⟺`. Not only is this less confusing for the reader, since you aren't paying attention to the forward direction you may inadvertantly assert false facts by displaying a stronger symbol than intended.
3. Writing `x+3 = 1+3 = 4` instead of `x+3 = 1+3 ,  x+3 = 4` makes it easier for both the reader and yourself.

---

**Addendum corresponding to the OP's new comment and edit**

> Doubtless, I know that the RHS's roots satisfy the LHS!

What you're saying here is exactly what it means to prove `LHS ⟸ RHS`: saying that the root $a$ satisfies the equation $x^3+7=11$ means that plugging in $x{=}a$ makes the equation true.

> merely verifies the $\color{blue}\impliedby$ for merely 2 integers of $x$! We need to prove the $\color{blue}\impliedby \forall \, x.$

Let's make explicit the key point of the above answer: to prove $$\color{red}{x+3}=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}\impliedby x=-2\:\:\text{or}\:\:1\tag1$$ means to argue that $$\text{for each }x,\big(x=-2{\implies} \color{red}{x+3}=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}\big)\\\quad\textbf{and}\quad\text{for each }x,\big(x=1{\implies} \color{red}{x+3}=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}\big).$$ In particular, say for $x{=7},$ we have $$\big(\text{False}{\implies} \text{False} \big)\\\quad\textbf{and}\quad\big(\text{False}{\implies} \text{False} \big),$$ that is, two [true implications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false). So, statement $(1)$ is true for $-2$ and $1$ and ***trivially true*** for every other real number; that is, **statement $\boldsymbol{(1)}$ is true for every real value of $\boldsymbol x.$** The word 'trivially' means that that portion of the proof is tacit; a succinct proof is more welcome than a tedious proof.

> Hence our conclusion must express the red functions in terms of $x$!

Alright, then let's make explicit this line from above: $$\color{red}{x+3}=4=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}.\tag2$$ This means $$\color{red}{x+3}=4\\\text{and}\quad\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}=4;\\\text{therefore}\quad \color{red}{x+3}=\color{violet}{(x+1)^2}.$$ We are allowed to read an equality from either side, due to the symmetric property of equality.

> I don't understand your first sentence "Replace the logically incorrect `or` with `and` or `but` or `while` or somesuch."

I'm saying that there's a difference between asserting that statements $A$ **and** $B$ are true, and asserting that either statement $A$ **or** $B$ is true. In the former, both statements are true; in the latter it could be that $A$ is false while $B$ is true. (The former implies the latter, but not vice versa.) In our above proof, we do require that both statements be true.

To reiterate what I said before: `(A or B) implies C` is logically equivalent to `(A implies C) and (B implies C)`, not to `(A implies C) or (B implies C)`.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer for the OP. Just as simple as it needs to be. +1

Comment: Many thanks! $\color{red}{1.}$  Your answer shall be easier to read, if you merge your addendum into your answer? For instance, rather than an addendum to clarify your original sentence, you can simply re-write your sentence "Replace the logically incorrect or with and or but or while or somesuch." $\color{red}{2.}$  Alas I can't accept 2 answers. I can't decide between yours and lone student's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4702943), but I chose [lone student](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/460967/lone-student) because he has less reputation. Hope this is OK!

Comment: Many thanks again. Let me contemplate whether to roll back to your title. You can retain all these comments, no need to delete them.

Answer (score 3):

To deduce
$$f(x)=g(x)\impliedby x=a$$
in case 2, simply check that
$$f(a)=g(a).$$

And to deduce
$$f(x)=g(x)\impliedby (x=a\lor x=b)$$
in case 1 and 3, simply check that
$$f(a)=g(a)\text{ and }f(b)=g(b).$$

1. $f(x)=x+3,$ $g(x)=(x+1)^2,$ $f(-2)=1=g(-2),$ $f(1)=4=g(1).$
2. $f(x)=\sqrt{x+3},$ $g(x)=x+1,$ $f(1)=2=g(1).$
3. $f(x)=x^2,$ $g(x)=x,$ $f(0)=0=g(0),$ $f(1)=1=g(1).$

Comment: Please, explain the downvote.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Thank you. Doubtless, daughter knows how to evaluate functions, and knows that $f(a)=g(a)\text{ and }f(b)=g(b)$ in each of your 3 equations. But why does this suffice? This feels inadequate, because you proved the $\Longleftarrow$ for merely 2 values, a & b. To prove $f(x)=g(x)\impliedby (x=a\lor x=b) \; \forall \, x$ , mustn't  $f(x), g(x)$ (the functions that I colored in red) appear in your final equation in terms of $x$?

Comment: I proved the $\impliedby$ not for merely 2 values but for all. $(\forall x)\Big[(x=a\lor x=b)\implies P(x)\Big]$ is rigorously equivalent to $P(a)\land P(b),$ because [$(\forall x)\Big[x=a\implies P(x)\Big]$ is equivalent to $P(a).$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) Maybe your misunderstanding is about the scope of the $\forall x.$ Beware it is the on whole formula inside my square brackets. Not only on one side of the $\impliedby.$

Answer (score 2):

The deduction from $x=0$ to $x^2=x$, for example, is quite intuitive.
After all, $0^2=0$.
If you are wondering what the formal reasoning
behind this deduction is,
it is the [axiom schemas of equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms),
specifically the axiom schema of substitution for formulas:

> For all variables $x$ and $y$, and any formula $\varphi(x)$,
> if $\varphi'$ is obtained by replacing any number of free occurances of $x$ in $\varphi$ with $y$, such that these remain free occurances of $y$, then
> $$ x=y \implies (\varphi \implies \varphi'). $$

This does require some familiarity in logic to understand fully,
but we can look at an example.
Suppose we want to show that $x=0\implies x^2=x$.
First, we have $x=0\implies 0=x$
(this is known as the symmetry of equality,
which can be deduced from the axiom schemas of equality).
From the axiom of substitution,
we know that
$$
0=x \implies (0^2=0\implies x^2=x).
$$
We know that $0^2=0$ is true,
so $0^2=0\implies x^2=x$ is logically equivalent to $x^2=x$.
Chaining together all those implications,
we have $x=0\implies x^2=x$.

Now, you can apply the axiom schemas of equality to prove all the implications in question,
but you can also show that $a=b\implies f(a)=f(b)$
and apply this instead
to avoid all the hassles.

Comment: Thank you. Undoubtedly, I know that $0^2 = 0.$ But why does this suffice? This feels inadequate, because you proved the $\Longleftarrow$ for merely one value, $x = 0$. To prove $x=y \implies (\varphi \implies \varphi')$ , mustn't  $\varphi, \varphi'$ (the functions that I colored in red) appear in your final equation in terms of $x$?

Comment: @user1176240 Because you _are_ proving $x^2=x$ for one value only, namely $x=0$. You are verifying that $x=0$ is a solution to $x^2=x$. If we say that $x=a$ is a solution of an equation, it means that when $x$ is replaced by $a$, the equation asserts a true statement.

Answer (score 1):

(Adapted from my comments.)

Let's analyse the situation on one of your examples: $x+3=(x+1)^2\impliedby x=-2\text{ or }x=1$.

It seems that the real question here is: obviously we can substitute $x=-2$ and $x=1$ into the LHS and see that the equation is satisfied. But, *why is this enough*? Why don't we need to substitute any other $x$ or provide some generic proof that would work for every $x$? It feels a bit like cheating, doesn't it?

In fact, it is not cheating and is completely legitimate. To prove the converse implication $\impliedby$, you only need to prove the LHS is true *when the RHS is true*. (Which in our case means only checking $x=-2$ and $x=1$.) It is *irrelevant* whether the LHS is true when the RHS is false.

Recall the truth table for implication:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}p&q&p\implies q\\\hline\bot&\bot&\top\\\bot&\top&\top\\\top&\bot&\bot\\\top&\top&\top\end{array}$$

The entire implication is true when the premise $p$ is false. The only way for the implication to be false is when the premise $p$ is true and the conclusion $q$ is false.

This closely matches natural logic. If you want to check if the sentence "All fish live in the water" is true, you *only need to check the fish*. (And, if you find one that does not live in the water, then it is false; otherwise it is true.) You don't need to check any other non-fish animals, say mammals. Whether they live in the water is irrelevant (and, as a matter of fact some do, and some don't). The same as it is irrelevant, in your case, whether the LHS is true for the $x$ that is neither $1$ nor $−2$.